# Why self.email and self._email are always equal to each other in below python class with @property?

Tags: python, properties, underscore.js

I got an example of the usage of @property from this blog: https://tomayko.com/blog/2005/getters-setters-fuxors. After running below code from the article, I noticed that self.email and self._email are equal and don't know why?

```
class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name=None, last_name=None,
                 display_name=None, email=None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.display_name = display_name
        self.email = email  #1 here the variable name is "email"

    def print_info(self):
        print self.display_name, "<" + self.email + ">"

    def set_email(self, value):
        if '@' not in value:
            raise Exception("This doesn't look like an email address.")
        self._email = value #2 here the name is "_email" with a leading underscore

    def get_email(self):
        return self._email #3 here with a leading underscore too

    email = property(get_email, set_email) #4 the name is "email" without underscore
C = Contact('a','b','c','d@email.com')
print C.email
C.email = 'e@emailcom'
print C.email
```

By executing the code step by step, I noticed that these two variables are always the same. How did this happen? I wonder what is the function behind it and support this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to grasp what you are trying to do but The variable _setemail is mentionned two times but neither of them is mentionned for your output. Also look up the LEGB rule that might help you to understand what the program will prioritize.

Comment: I added 4 comments. It may better to express what I tried to understand. Thank you.